# Python version in Visual Studio console

Tags: python, visual-studio, console, interpreter

I have set the interpreter to 3.8.2 but when I type in the console python --version it gives me the python 2.7.2. Why is that and how to change the console version so I can run my files with Python 3? In windows console I have of course python 3 when I type the --version.

Comment: i suggest you add more detail about your settings procedure.

Answer (score 1):

The console displayed by VSCode is basically an ordinary terminal. When you run the python file from VSCode using the green arrow at the top, it will call the appropriate python version displayed at the bottom of the VSCode window. You can also see what VSCode executes in the terminal seeing to which python its pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

**(Assuming you use Visual Studio Code with the Python Extension)**
The interpreter set in visual studio has nothing to do with the terminal python version when you run `python --version`.

`python --version` is bound to what python version is bound to 'python' in your environment variables.

Try `python3 --version` in the visual studio console to see what version is bound to `python3`.
If this is the right version, use `python3` in the visual studio console from now on.

Comment: yes I have tried python3 but nothing is happening, either with
python3 --version
or
python3 helloworld.py

Can I change what is bound to python in the VS console? I thought it is just normal PowerShell but not, it is as I see the internal console of VS with its own "rules".

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio Code? If so, are you using "Terminal" or "Debug Console"?